# Take snapshot of view / WebView programmatically

Tags: iphone, view, webview, image, snapshot

I want to take a snapshot of a view (WebView) or, if that is not possible, the whole screen, so I can save it into the user's photo gallery. I was wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the image, you'll want to use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

[theView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then, to save to the Photos Library:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,nil,NULL,NULL);
```