# iphone : How to convert webpage(UIWebView) to pdf

Tags: iphone

i want to convert my webpage(displayed in UIWebView) contents in pdf file.

which can be stored at perticular directory (document dir/any user defined dir).

So later on it can be viewable to user either internet connection not available.

is there any possibilities to perform this functionality.

how can i do this...

Thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image might be your best option. See [Take snapshot of view / WebView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501496/take-snapshot-of-view-webview-programmatically)

To get the image, you'll want to use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

[theView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then, to save to the Photos Library:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,nil,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: is this will capture all the content even the scrollable content out side of the screen(means content below the viewable area)... ?

or only snapshot(means only viewable area) ?

Comment: you control it based on the value to pass to the UIGraphicsBeingImageContext function. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Comment: thanks for your responce psychotik, but i want to convert it in pdf...is there any way ?
or can we open pdf from website in UIWebView ? or not ?
if yes then can we save it to the local disk space in iPhone ?
please ans all my questions because i am little bit confuse about it...

Comment: To answer your question about opening a PDF in a UIWebView, it is possible to do this. I recommend having a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview.